# Парсинг html страницы в jQuery объект

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется вся страница, начиная от `<!DOCTYPE html>`, заканчивая `</html>`.
Как мне эту строку распарсить в объект jQuery что бы у меня получился `html`?

Сейчас же я получаю набор из всех элементов которые есть в `body`, а мне нужно все, включая `head` и `body`.

Еще проблема с парсингом в экранировании символов, таких как `"`.

Comment: А что это за зверь такой `объект jQuery `?

Comment: @Дмытрык, объект, возвращаемый методом `jQuery` (псевдоним - `$`).

Comment: @Deonis, понятно)

Answer (score 0):

Интересующая Вас информация содержится в `document.documentElement`

```js
console.log(document.documentElement)
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте $($.parseHTML('Ваша строка-страница'));

```js
var dom_nodes = $($.parseHTML('<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US"><head><title>HTML Examples</title><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><meta name="Keywords" content="HTML,CSS,JavaScript,SQL,PHP,jQuery,XML,DOM,Bootstrap,Web development,W3C,tutorials,programming,training,learning,quiz,primer,lessons,references,examples,source code,colors,demos,tips"><meta name="Description" content="Well organized and easy to understand Web building tutorials with lots of examples of how to use HTML, CSS, JavaScript, SQL, PHP, and XML."><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/w3css/4/w3.css"><style>a:hover,a:active{color:#4CAF50}</style></header><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p><div><input type="text" value="тестовое значение" /></div></body></html>'));

console.log(dom_nodes);
alert( dom_nodes.find('input').val() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: уже пробовал. Ошибка парсинга. Именно в моём случае ошибка парсинга.

Comment: а что провоцирует ошибку?

Comment: попробуйте $('<div/>').html('Ваша строка-страница').contents()

Comment: возвращает список элементов просто, типо text, comment и т.д.